# Read, extract href from anchor tags and scan tag for a particular value/position

Tags: python, url, href

I am trying to read the HTML from the data files below, extract the href= vaules from the anchor tags, scan for a tag that is in a particular position relative to the first name in the list, follow that link and repeat the process a number of times and report the last name I find:

(URL:  http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Emir.html)

Find the link at position 18 (the first name is 1). Follow that link. Repeat this process 7 times. The answer is the last name that you retrieve.
Hint: The first character of the name of the last page that you will load is: M

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = input('Enter - ')
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

tags = soup('a')
for tag in tags:
    print(tag.get('href', None))
```

Comment: Looks like this is some kind of homework assigned to u. Is it ok for ur teacher/professor if I help u with this?

Comment: It is for a course in Coursera. I tried myself and couldn't figure it out, so thought of posting it here! I am working now :P not at uni anymore... I wish!

Answer (score 1):

You can put the whole thing within a loop:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = 'http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Emir.html'

for x in range(7):
    if x != 0:
        html = urllib.request.urlopen(tag, context=ctx).read()
    else:
        html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    tag = soup.find_all('a')[17]['href']

print(tag)
```

Output:

```
http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Maya.html
```

Comment: Can you pls explain, which it is range(7)- what does this refer to? Same for the final line- why 17? Is it with reference to the 17th line?

Comment: `range(7)` : Repeats the loop for 7 times. *why 17?* - `17` is the index of the 18th element, which is the 18th link

Comment: Sorry one last thing- why did we repeat it 7 times?? Why not 6 or more than 7? Thanks.

Comment: U have mentioned that u wanna repeat this process for 7 times in ur question.